# How to audit database user password changes in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, audit

I want to record how many times or which user accounts passwords were changed using Oracle database auditing techniques. I also want to record any password changes done to system user account.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50000

Comment: Followed the document and set audit_trail parameter to DB_EXTENDED,

Comment: Then created a test user, connected to that user and tried to change password of that user. I could not find any entry in `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL`.

Answer (score 1):

Auditing can capture when a user changes their own password. If a sys or admin user changes the password of another user that can't be captured in auditing.

You can use [this metalink doc (ID 419942.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=347394678297561&id=419942.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=yv144qu0c_4) to create a system trigger and change it to add an entry in a temp table.